# Should I tell a potential employer I like them better than a company I already have an offer with?

Tags: professionalism, job-offer

I have received a job offer from company A who needs a response in 6 days. I am reasonably hoping for an offer from company B. I prefer company B to company A and intend to write company B an email to attempt to hurry them along (although, its [been argued](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/career-management/what-do-you-do-with-a-job-offer-while-youre-waiting-for-another-offer/) this rarely works, I think its still worth a try).

How should I word this email? Its been [suggested](http://money.usnews.com/money/blogs/outside-voices-careers/2009/02/02/how-to-juggle-a-job-offer-when-youre-waiting-for-another) to say "I got an offer from A, *but I like you better*." whereas [others](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/how-do-i-balance-a-job-offer-with-potential-offers/) have said "I got an offer from A [period]" **Is one better?**

In my particular situation, company A is acceptable (albeit not ideal) and I don't want to play delay games that might leave me with no offer at all.

Comment: That doesn't seems a good idea.
Why would they hurry when they know you prefer them ?

Comment: @Walfrat: It doesn't help if a candidate prefers them but then accepts a different offer that he has in the pocket instead of waiting.

Comment: Not really relevant, but company B gave me an offer that I accepted. It's been a great job. Yay!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have received a job offer from company A who needs a response in 6 days. I am reasonably hoping for an offer from company B.

I agree with you that since you have an offer with company **A**, it is worth a try to challenge company **B** into making you an offer.

The Human resource department deals with that kind of situation pretty often. Usually when you apply for a job, you don't apply for a single job. They know that. Telling them right now that you have an offer with another company might have two outcomes : they align with the offer from company A ; they refuse to hire you.

If you don't tell them anyways they might or might not hire you but you cannot know for sure. If once their recruiting process is done and they decide to pick you, then you will feel frustrated and them too because they will have spent time on your case.

> Its been suggested to say "I got an offer from A, but I like you better." whereas others have said "I got an offer from A [period]" Is one better?

In this situation what I would recommend you is to be as honest as possible and to write **"I got an offer from A, but I like you better."** because you really need to show interest.

By telling them "I got an offer from A [period]" it might get interpreted like you would tell them that you like offer A, and that they should give you an answer right away. But not describing you like company B better.

> How should I word this email? 
>   Say in your e-mail exactly what you have explained here :

1 
 - You had an offer from company A, which is a nice offer.

2
 - You prefer company B (explain again why you are motivated to work for them)

3
 - You would like to have an offer from them

4
 - You don't want to rush them but you need to give an answer to company A in a few days.

5
 - If they refuse or don't answer on time you accept company A's offer